# How to insert data as JSON object with Gremlin API in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

How to insert data as a JSON object in Gremlin

Currently, the following query is used to insert person object with some properties:

```
g.addV('person').property('firstName', 'Thomas').property('lastName', 'Andersen').property('age', 44).property('userid', 101)
```

With the above approach, I have to call `.property()` method for each attribute and there could be more than 50 attributes in my object/class.

Is ther anyway to insert the complete object in one call

```
var personData = {
    firstName: 'Thomas',
    lastName: 'Andersen',
    age: 44,
    userid: 101

};

g.addV('person', personData);
// OR
g.addV('person').data(personData);
```

Please note that, I am using MS Cosmos DB Gremlin API with NodeJs.

Answer (score 2):

No such method or api which is similar to your imagination could be found in [gremlin api](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/).

According to your description,it seems that you just want to bulk import multiple properties into Vertex.I'd recommand you to loop the property json array or json object(`for key in obj....`) to execute `.property('XXX', 'YYY')` in the bulk.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking alike.

Comment: @MujassirNasir hi,any updates here? If you think my answer is meaningful,would you please accept it?Or you have more maturely idea?